# How to repeat short sequences of characters

Tags: neovim, repeated-commands

I want to replace a sequence of 6 hex digits (hex RGB) with new values, but I want to repeat a 2-tuple 3 times.

For example:

Start: `#ea9081` (with the cursor on 'e')

Desired: `#f0f0f0`

I know I can do `6rf`, as an example to change all 6 values to 'f', or `dte3if0<esc>` to delete to end of word and repeat-insert 3 times.  But is there a way to modify something along the lines of `3cef0<esc>` to repeat a change three times?  Or some magic with `s` (substitute)?

Comment: I'd just use `cw` and then `f0f0f0`; you can probably be more "clever" about it, but you'll spend more time on the cleverness than you'd save repeating `f0` two times.

Comment: @MartinTournoij Yeah I guess this question makes more sense for a snippet longer than two characters and/or repeated way more than 3 times :-)

Comment: Good point about the time spent, but I just felt like the general case of repeating sequences of characters must exist in vim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `3Rf0<Esc>`.

The [`R`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#R) command is similar to `r`, but it replaces multiple characters and not just a single one. It takes an `<Esc>` to leave Insert (Replace) mode.

You can also use `.` to repeat a Replace action, and you can repeat it with a count. For example, you can use `Rf0<Esc>` to replace the first instance, followed by `l2.` if you realize after the first replacement that you'd like to have it done two more times.

Comment: Not any shorter, but easier for my brain: `Rf0<esc>..` (may need some `l`s to move right)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble You actually need to move the cursor here. `Rf0<Esc>l.l.` works, or better `Rf0<Esc>l2.` if you realize after the replacement that you'd like to do it two more times.

Comment: I was also trying to figure this problem out with `.`, but couldn't get it to work with my old thinking.  Replace-mode does the trick!

Comment: @jdk1.0 Updated the answer to include the possibility of using `2.` here too!